# Rails 4 - How to display and play a video file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, paperclip

In rails 4.2.4, I have uploaded one video file using `paperclip`. How can I display and play it? I have tried to display using `<video src="<%= video.document.url %>" controls></video>` but it is showing route error.

File url is `http://localhost:3000/public/videos/user_1/3/sample_HD.mp4?1461059434`

File which is saves under `/public/videos/user_1/3/` folder.

How can I display and play a saved video? Do I need to use other method?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the video_tag helper which builds an HTML 5 tag. Video files are loaded from 'public/videos' by default.

```
<%= video_tag "truffle1.mp4", :size => "320x240", :controls => true %>
```

Comment: I have tried using `<%= video_tag video.document_file_name, :controls => true %>`, still route error is there. Generated HTML is, `<video controls="controls" src="http://localhost:3000/videos/sample_HD.mp4"></video>`

Answer (score 0):

Changing `<video src="<%= video.document.url %>" controls></video>` to `<video src=<%= video.document.url %> controls></video>` should fix your problem.